# Роутинг и входящие данные yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть правило для роутинга `'search/<description:[\d]+>' => 'search'`, где входящие `description` идет как данные для поиска по базе, так вот, если я введу интовые данные, то поиск проходит, но, если я введу стринговые данные, то оно ищет такую страницу, и конечно у меня такой нету и выдает 400. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Измените правило на `'search/<description:[\w-]+>' => 'search'`.